# Cannot retrieve data from RoomDatabase using RecylerView Android

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to displaying data from roomdatabase using recylerView. i can see the data is in table in roomdatabase but i am unable to show using recylerView. please check my code and let me know where i am wrong. thanks very much.

below is my Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "myExpense")
public class Expense {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int uid;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Amount")
public String amount;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Date")
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public Date date;

@ColumnInfo(name = "ExpenseType")
public String expenseType;

@ColumnInfo(name = "PaymentType")
public String paymentType;

public Expense(int uid, String amount, Date date, String expenseType, String paymentType) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.date = date;
    this.expenseType = expenseType;
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}

public int getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(int uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getExpenseType() {
    return expenseType;
}

public void setExpenseType(String expenseType) {
    this.expenseType = expenseType;
}

public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}

public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}
}
```

this is my Dao class

```
@Dao
public interface ExpenseDao {
@Insert
void insertExpense(Expense expense);

@Query( "SELECT *FROM myExpense" )
List<Expense> getAllExpenses();

@Query("SELECT SUM (Amount) From myExpense")
float getAllExpenseSum();
}
```

below is my Adapter class

```
public class ExpenseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpenseAdapter.myViewHolder> {

List<Expense> ExpenseList;
Context context;

public ExpenseAdapter(Context context,List<Expense> ExpenseList)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.ExpenseList=ExpenseList;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.expense_adapter, parent, false );
    return new myViewHolder ( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    Date date = ExpenseList.get ( position ).getDate ();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.UK );
    String stringDate = dateFormat.format ( date );

    holder.ExpenseAmountTxt.setText ( ExpenseList.get (position).getAmount () );
    holder.ExpenseTypeTxt.setText ( ExpenseList.get ( position ).getExpenseType () );
    holder.PaymentTypeTxt.setText ( ExpenseList.get ( position ).getPaymentType () );
    holder.ExpenseDateTxt.setText ( stringDate );

    String ExpenseType=(String) holder.ExpenseTypeTxt.getText ();
    if (ExpenseType.equals ( "Oil" ))
    {
        holder.ExpenseIcon.setImageResource ( R.drawable.petrol_icon );
    }
    else if (ExpenseType.equals ( "Maintainance" ))
    {
        holder.ExpenseIcon.setImageResource ( R.drawable.maintenance );
    }
    else if (ExpenseType.equals ( "Food" ))
    {
        holder.ExpenseIcon.setImageResource ( R.drawable.food );
    }
    else if (ExpenseType.equals ( "Other" ))
    {
        holder.ExpenseIcon.setImageResource ( R.drawable.othersicon );
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ExpenseList.size ();
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView ExpenseAmountTxt,ExpenseTypeTxt,PaymentTypeTxt,ExpenseDateTxt;
    ImageView ExpenseIcon;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );

        ExpenseAmountTxt= itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ExpensetxtViewAmount );
        ExpenseTypeTxt= itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ExpenseType);
        PaymentTypeTxt= itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ExpenseAmountType  );
        ExpenseDateTxt= itemView.findViewById ( R.id.ExpensedateText );

    }
}
}
```

and this is how i am trying to display

```
public class Income_Expense extends Fragment {

BottomBar bottomBar;
RoomAdapter roomAdapter;
ExpenseAdapter expenseAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate ( R.layout.income_expense, container, false );

    bottomBar= view.findViewById ( R.id.bottomBar );
    recyclerView= view.findViewById ( R.id.myrecView2 );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ()  ) );

   bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener ( new OnTabSelectListener () {
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
           if (tabId==R.id.Expenses)
           {
               AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder ( getContext (), AppDatabase.class, "myexpense" ).allowMainThreadQueries ().build ();
               ExpenseDao expenseDao = db.expenseDao ();
               List<Expense> expenses= expenseDao.getAllExpenses ();
               expenseAdapter = new ExpenseAdapter ( getContext (), expenses );
               recyclerView.setAdapter ( expenseAdapter  );
               expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();


           }
       }
   } );



    return view;
}
```

}

and last class is appDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {Income.class,Expense.class}, version = 
2,exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract UserDao userDao();
public abstract ExpenseDao expenseDao();}
```

Thanks for your time. i am really stuck with this task here. thanks again

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eg34.png)

Comment: Can you show your error message? Seems your code is incomplete.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont get any error message its just not displaying anything.

Comment: I think your Integration step is not correctly. You may find the right way at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room.

Comment: I also find you use the wrong database name. You use "myExpense" on Expense.java, and "myexpense" on Fragment. If you are sure your Integration is correctly, you can use log to print your data when you call getAllExpenses()

Answer (score 0):

```
 bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener ( new OnTabSelectListener () {
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
           if (tabId==R.id.Expenses)
           {
               AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder ( getContext (), AppDatabase.class, "myexpense" ).allowMainThreadQueries ().build ();
               ExpenseDao expenseDao = db.expenseDao ();
               List<Expense> expenses= expenseDao.getAllExpenses ();
               expenseAdapter = new ExpenseAdapter ( getContext (), expenses );
               recyclerView.setAdapter ( expenseAdapter  );
               expenseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();


           }
       }
   } );
```

is not myexpense ->myExpense this correct.

Comment: Thanks solve the issue using your solution. thanks again